# How do I call a child's method from the parent class?

Tags: android, inheritance

Let's say I have a class, *ChildFragment* that inherits from a *ParentFragment*. The purpose is to have several Activities and Fragments with buttons that are commonly used handled by one *ParentFragment*.

When the user presses a refresh button, it will call a `refresh()`  function in the `ParentFragment`. However, the action of actually downloading this file is handled by the ChildFragment, because every fragment has different content. So I want this ParentFragment to call something in the child, whenever the `refresh()` is done.

How can I do this? Or if there is a better way of doing it, it would help too.

Comment: Put a virtual refresh in parent and call it. Child must override it.

Comment: you mean `abstract` not virtual :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override the `refresh` method in child fragments.

```
public class PFragment extends Fragment{
  protected void refresh(){
    //Common stuff here
  }
}
```

In child class ovveride the refresh method

```
public class CFragment extends PFragment{
 public void onClick(){
  super.refresh();
 }

@Override
protected void refresh(){
 //Custom stuff here
}

}
```

Comment: But note the parent refresh method will not be executed unless you add super.refresh() to the child class refresh method

Comment: Edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
class ParentFragment() {

    protected void refresh() {
        // general code when refresh every fragment
    }
}

class ChildFragment1 extend ParentFragment {
    @Override
    public void refresh() {
         super.refresh();
         // code for refresh child fragment1
    }
}

class ChildFragment2 extend ParentFragment {
    @Override
    public void refresh(); {
         super.refresh();
         // code for refresh child fragment2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the child classes to have to implement refresh and call super.refresh, define an abstract method in the ParentFragment for the downloadFile method, then implement this in the child(ren) classes:

```
class ParentFragment {
    public void refresh() {
        downloadFile();
    }

    protected abstract void downloadFile();
}

class ChildFragment extends ParentFragment {
    @Override
    protected void downloadFile() {
        // do the download here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)! - simplifies the communication between components